# How to modify ToggleButton behaviour with or without xml in Android

Tags: android, xml, togglebutton, settext

I've to do a memo card game in android for my project. As for now i'm at the stage where i try to figure out the basic shape of my app.

I've read some tutorials, but i can;t figure out how to modify a lot of dynamically created buttons (ie. in 'for' loop), from xml, or even from the code.
To make my question clear here's the code i made

```
package piotrek.test1;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;


public class test1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<Integer> listaKart = new ArrayList<Integer>();    
private int rozmiar = 0;    
private int licznik = 0;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TworzKarty();
    //tu tworzymy definicje nowego wygladu (layout) czyli w formie tabeli

    TableLayout layout = new TableLayout (this);
    layout.setLayoutParams( new TableLayout.LayoutParams(4,5) );

    //ustawienie odstepow do 'scian'

    layout.setPadding(10,10,10,10);

    //petle 'populujace' miejsca w tabeli przyciskami

    for (int f=0; f<=5; f++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        for (int c=0; c<=4; c++) {
            ToggleButton b = new ToggleButton (this);
            //b.setText(""+f+c);
            b.setText(Integer.toString(listaKart.get(licznik)));
            b.setTextSize(10.0f);
            b.setTextColor(Color.rgb( 100, 200, 200));
            b.setOnClickListener(this);
            tr.addView(b, 60,60);
            licznik++;
        } // for
        layout.addView(tr);
    } // for

    super.setContentView(layout);
} // ()


public void TworzKarty(){

for (int i=0;i<=14;i++){
    this.listaKart.add(i);
    this.listaKart.add(i);
}
//pomieszanie kolejnosci numerków
Collections.shuffle(listaKart);
rozmiar=listaKart.size();


}



public void onClick(View view) {
//((Button) view).setText("*");
//((Button) view).setEnabled(false);
if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
    Toast.makeText(test1.this, Integer.toString(rozmiar), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} 
else {
    Toast.makeText(test1.this, "Not checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}




} // class
```

What happens when i run the app is, that i have 30 togglebuttons on the screen, each of them has a number form 0 to 14 (15 pairs). That's what i wanted to have, but when i press any of them buttons besides showing the toast button text changes form what i want it to be to ON and then after another press to OFF.
I can't figure out how to control this behaviour - i would really appreciate some tips on how to achieve this strictly in code or using xml. Another case is how to use xml to define such layout and randomness of the text set on buttons.

Comment: `import android.view.*;` Does it really compile when you do that? I thought you couldn't do wildcard imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add

```
b.setTextOff(Integer.toString(listaKart.get(licznik)));
b.setTextOn(Integer.toString(listaKart.get(licznik)));
```

to your inner for() loop, the buttons will always display their position in the list, whether toggled on or off.

Comment: Thank You very much, i knew it has to be something simple, but i could'nt figure it out on my own. This works perfect, and leaves me space for future modification for the game purpose.